# Add an "s" to the end of a string, depending on a variable

Tags: swift, optimization

I'd like to append an s to the end of a string, if the value of a variable is > 1.

There are obviously several ways to accomplish this - for example:

```
if(points == 1) {
     points_as_string = "1 Point"
} else {
     points_as_string = "\(points) Points"
}
```

A shorter version could be:

```
points_as_string = (points == 1 ? "1 Point" : "\(points) Points")
```

An even shorter version would be:

```
points_as_string = "\(points) Point" + (points == 1 ? "" : "s")
```

Is it possible to write something even shorter than that, or is that as good as it gets?

Comment: For proper pluralization in multiple languages you would use NSLocalizedString and  .stringsdict files, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW10. A simple example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862960/ios-swift-and-localizedstringwithformat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only very slightly shorter:

```
points_as_string = "\(points) Point\(points == 1 ? "" : "s")"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter version that uses a dictionary lookup and the *nil coalescing operator* `??`:

```
points_as_string = "\(points) Point\([1:""][points] ?? "s")"
```